# View container logs from inside container

Tags: docker, logging

I know the way by checking `/var/lib/docker/containers/<containerid>-json.log` from the host(including mapping this volume), and through docker client API, but is there any other way viewing log from inside a container?

Comment: The docker logs are the /dev/stderr and /dev/stdout . Maybe you can try to read them.

Answer (score 0):

If your image runs a non-interactive process such as a web server or a database, that application may send its output to log files instead of STDOUT and STDERR.

*** If you use a logging driver which sends logs to a file, an external host, a database, or another logging back-end you may not see the logs.